# Skip some letters in subequations numbering/lettering

Tags: numbering, subequations

I use subequations with code like this

```
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
1=2\\
3=4\\
x=y
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

and it numbers the three lines as (1a), (1b) and (1c). I want to change it so that it instead numbers it (1a), (1d) and (1f), i.e., I want to skip some letters. How could I do that?

Comment: `... \tag{1d} \\ ` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I don't want to do it manually myself because the set of equations is much larger and would prefer automatic updates if I change stuff later

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd define a `\skipeqs` command to be used at the beginning of the relevant row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\skipeqs}[1]{\addtocounter{equation}{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
1=2 \label{one} \\
\skipeqs{2}
3=4 \label{two} \\
\skipeqs{1}
x=y \label{three}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\eqref{one}
\eqref{two}
\eqref{three}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could insert the instructions `\addtocounter{equation}{2}` and `\stepcounter{equation}` on lines 2 and 3 of the three-equation construct. (`\stepcounter{equation}` does the same as `\addtocounter{equation}{1}`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}      % for align and subequations environments
\setlength\textwidth{8cm} % just for this document

\begin{document}
\noindent
original form:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
1&=2\\
3&=4\\
x&=y
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

\bigskip\noindent
with \verb+\addtocounter{equation}{2}+ and \verb+\stepcounter{equation}+:
\begin{subequations}
\begin{align}
1&=2\\
3&=4 \addtocounter{equation}{2} \\
x&=y \stepcounter{equation}
\end{align}
\end{subequations}
\end{document}
```